# Generating AngularJS documentation without using grunt/bower

Tags: angularjs, jsdoc

We have an **angularJS** project and have been using the `@ngdoc` notation as seen in the angular source code, however we don't use grunt / bower and would like to generate the documentation. Is there a program which does this without relying on grunt / bower config files?

I've looked at **ngdocs**, **grunt-ngdocs** and **grunt-ngdoc**. Ideally I just want to feed in a regular expression for our js folder and have a html index with links to the documentation for each module.

I've tried jsdoc but it doesn't recognise a lot of the ngdoc annotations resulting in a blank index.html

Answer (score 1):

You could try a *template* for **jsdoc**. I found **[angular-jsdoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-jsdoc)** very useful.

I would recommend evaluating this, as it requires nothing more than jsdoc installed. And it is able to read an process `@ngDoc` tags.